# How to retrieve auto referenced rows recursive

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, where-clause

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE poke_evolutions (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    poke_id VARCHAR(20),
    parent VARCHAR(20,
    method VARCHAR(20)
)
```

And this sample data:

```
INSERT INTO poke_evolutions (id,poke_id,parent,method)
     VALUES (1,'Pichu',null,'Happiness')
INSERT INTO poke_evolutions (id,poke_id,parent,method)
     VALUES (2,'Pikachu','Pichu','Thunderstone')
INSERT INTO poke_evolutions (id,poke_id,parent,method)
    VALUES (3,'Raichu','Pikachu','Thunderstone')
INSERT INTO poke_evolutions (id,poke_id,parent,method)
    VALUES (4,'Raichu Alola','Pikachu','Thunderstone')
```

I need a query that, given a 'poke_id'  or 'parent', returns the complete family of evolutions. For example:

```
Given "Pikachu" it must retrieve ids: 1,2,3,4

Given "Raichu Alola" it must retrieve ids: 1,2,3,4
```

EDIT: the explanation of the logic of this:

A Pokemon can evolve , pokemon can have evolutions , pre-evolutions and splited evolutions :

Example of splitted evolutions:
[image]

Example of normal evolution:

[image]

Comment: Please explain the logic. It is not obvious if you are not a Pokemon fan.

Comment: Select **ONE** DBMS, then remove unrelated tag.

Comment: @GMB edited adding explanation

Comment: @Akina can you provide me an SQL sentence query ?

Comment: Is the data design from you or have you pumped it elsewhere? Because frankly it seems bad to me. This is not the right way to store and manage hierarchical data.  It can work, with complicated queries, but you will have a lot of issues at some point. For instance you should have a character table, with columns `ID` number, `Name` (Pichu, Pikachu, Raichu), `Instance` NULL, 1,  2 (for your 2 instances of Raichu). And then in your evo table the columns should be ID, character_id, parent_char_id, description_of_evo. Way too long for a comment, I hope you get it.

Comment: @ThomasG For simplcitiy sake , I 've replaced the IDs of the characters by their current names (I think that Pichu or Pikachu are more easy to understand than 90001 , and 90002) . However , I still need the query that search recursively/hierarchicaly in my table

Comment: What I tell you is that Characters and Evolutions are something different and they should be separated in 2 tables. One of them should handle the hierarchy, with 2 columns "Character_ID" and "Parent_Character_id", it can work in both tables. The very first parent (Pichu, Bulbasaur) as parent_id=NULL.That's the only efficient way to manage and query hirerachical data in SQL. But your main issue right now, is that your evo table stores a charchter in 3 columns : poke_id,evo,split_evo. This is plain wrong and will lead you to a lot of issues soon or late. Fix that first

Comment: If someone comes here with a query that solves your issue, it will only masks you the reality: your data modeling is wrong. And a lot of issues will arise at a later point. I could but I wont give you the answer, because it is NOT doing you a favor. On the contrary, if you change your data structure and to what I said, you will easily find a ton of hierarchical queries examples that will help you to achieve what you want, and beyond.

Comment: @ThomasG I've remodeled the data according to your comment (The names you see in the sampledata are just translations of the reald ID of the Pokemon that appears in another table) , can you provide me with an example of hierarchycal query  ?

Comment: @NexussimLements . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are using *and* the version.  I think your problem requires recursive CTEs and not all supported versions of the databases you originally tagged support them.

Comment: I only see now that @GordonLinoff replaced the original `mysql` tag with `sqlite`. If you arent using mysql as I thought, my answer wont work...

Comment: @ThomasG . . . I did not add the SQLite tag, I only removed both database tags and requested that the correct tag be added.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ah sorry, someone else did then. it was originally tagged MySQL. I fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are on MySQL v8 . If not that's a major issue because having the possibility to run recursive CTE is a luxury with hierarchical data. All what is below relies on CTE. This is still possible to do it without CTE, on MySQL 5, but I wont detail it here, because it has no future.

First of all, add a column that will stores the "origin" character of a certain "chain" of evolution. Why ? Because you are facing a typical situation where [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) is a very good thing.

If you don't add this column, you will have to do overcomplicated and unperformant queries all over the place to retrieve all the pokemons in the chain of a specific pokemon.

So start with

```
ALTER table poke_evolutions ADD origin (VARCHAR(20)) default NULL;
```

And then your table becomes

```
id  poke_id         parent         method         origin
1   Pichu                          Happiness    
2   Pikachu         Pichu          Thunderstone     
3   Raichu          Pikachu        Thunderstone     
4   Raichu Alola    Pikachu        Thunderstone     
5   Bulbasaur                      Happiness    
6   Ivysaur         Bulbasaur      Anything     
7   Venusaur        Ivysaur        Anything
```

But what is great, is that you can define once for all the `origin` value, using a recursive CTE that search the topmost parent of all your pokemons :

```
WITH recursive cte AS(
      SELECT *, poke_id AS topparent 
      FROM poke_evolutions 
      WHERE parent IS NULL
  UNION ALL
      SELECT p.*, c.topparent 
      FROM poke_evolutions p JOIN cte c ON c.poke_id = p.parent
      WHERE p.poke_id <> p.parent
)

select * from cte


id  poke_id         parent         method           origin  topparent
1   Pichu           Happiness                               Pichu
5   Bulbasaur       Happiness                               Bulbasaur
2   Pikachu         Pichu          Thunderstone             Pichu
6   Ivysaur         Bulbasaur      Anything                 Bulbasaur
3   Raichu          Pikachu        Thunderstone             Pichu
4   Raichu Alola    Pikachu        Thunderstone             Pichu
7   Venusaur    Ivysaur            Anything                 Bulbasaur
```

So just run an UPDATE query that uses your CTE, in order to fix the origin value definitively :

```
WITH recursive cte AS(
      SELECT *, poke_id AS topparent 
      FROM poke_evolutions 
      WHERE parent IS NULL
  UNION ALL
      SELECT p.*, c.topparent 
      FROM poke_evolutions p JOIN cte c ON c.poke_id = p.parent
      WHERE p.poke_id <> p.parent
)
UPDATE poke_evolutions p, cte c
SET p.origin= c.topparent
WHERE p.poke_id=c.poke_id;
```

Your table becomes :

```
SELECT * from  poke_evolutions;

id  poke_id         parent         method         origin
1   Pichu                          Happiness      Pichu
2   Pikachu         Pichu          Thunderstone   Pichu 
3   Raichu          Pikachu        Thunderstone   Pichu  
4   Raichu Alola    Pikachu        Thunderstone   Pichu  
5   Bulbasaur                      Happiness      Bulbasaur
6   Ivysaur         Bulbasaur      Anything       Bulbasaur
7   Venusaur        Ivysaur        Anything       Bulbasaur
```

And Now, you can easily do what you wanted in the first place

> Given "Pikachu" it must retrieve ids: 1,2,3,4
>
> Given "Raichu Alola" it must retrieve ids: 1,2,3,4

With Pichu

```
select poke_id from poke_evolutions 
where origin = (select origin from poke_evolutions WHERE poke_id='Pichu');

poke_id
Pichu
Pikachu
Raichu
Raichu Alola
```

With Raichu Alola

```
select poke_id from poke_evolutions 
where origin = (select origin from poke_evolutions WHERE poke_id='Raichu Alola');

poke_id
Pichu
Pikachu
Raichu
Raichu Alola
```

With Ivysaur

```
select poke_id from poke_evolutions 
where origin = (select origin from poke_evolutions WHERE poke_id='Ivysaur');

poke_id
Bulbasaur
Ivysaur
Venusaur
```

And finally, add an **index** on your `origin` column, its your new friend ;)

Comment: Your answer is pure gold , thanks for the database optimization lesson of today !

Comment: @NexussimLements you are welcome. So I assume it was for MySQL and not sqlite. If so, edit your question and tag it properly. Master Gordon has removed hte MySQL tag